# Rank of the endomorphism group of a torsion-free abelian group of rank 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Exercise from Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra: If $G$ is a torsion-free abelian group of rank 1, prove that the additive group of $End(G)$ is torsion free of rank 1.

So I have $End(G) = Hom(G, G)$, and I think I need to show that $\mathbb{Q} \otimes Hom(G, G)$ is torsion-free of rank 1. But by a theorem in the book, we have $\mathbb{Q} \otimes Hom(G, G) = Hom(G, \mathbb{Q} \otimes G) = Hom(G, \mathbb{Q})$, but then I'm stuck here.

Any clues on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that Rotman defines "rank" to mean "dimension of $A \otimes \mathbb{Q}.$")

Your approach is right. Now we have an exact sequence (tautologically)
$$
0 \to G \to G \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to \frac{G \otimes \mathbb{Q}}{G} \to 0.
$$
The group on the far right is a torsion group. (An element of the form $ \sum g_i \otimes q_i$ is killed by the product of the denominators of the $q_i$). We may apply the exact functor $\text{Hom}( \_ ,\mathbb{Q})$ to deduce that the natural map

$$
 \text{Hom}(G \otimes \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}) \to \text{Hom}(G, \mathbb{Q})
$$
is an isomorphism. The left hand side is a one-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space by assumption and so we are done.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you very much! Although he uses a similar technique (choosing an exact sequence, applying a functor to it, and deducing some isomorphisms and stuff) at many places in the book, I still haven't developed the skill of using it yet.

Comment: Note to self: When $M$ is torsion, $Hom(M, \mathbb{Q}) = \{0\}$ hence we get the isomorphism we want.

Comment: @eatfood I said my sequence was exact "tautologically" but that is sloppy; $G \to G \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is injective iff $G$ is torsion-free, which, luckily, it is.